# socket.emit() not functional with the event defined in flask

Tags: javascript, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have this Javascript snippet

```
        document.addEventListener('click', event => {
            const element = event.target;
            if (element.className === 'list'){
                channel = element.getAttribute('data-channel');
                document.querySelector('#chatarea').innerHTML = "";
                socket.emit('loadmessage', {'channel': channel});
                localStorage.setItem('channel', channel);
            }

            if (element.className === 'sendmessage'){
                const channel = "sports";
                const name = document.querySelector('#displayname').data("displayname");
                const msg = document.querySelector('[name="message"]').value;
                const time = timeStamp();
                socket.emit('newmessage', {'channel': channel, 'name': name, 'msg': msg, 'time': time});
            }
        });
```

and this is the flask part

```
@socketio.on('loadmessage')
def loadmessage(data):
    print(f"loading the existing messages of {data}")
    channel = data["channel"]
    m = channels[channel]
    print(f"m is {m}")
    emit('message loader', m, broadcast=False)

@socketio.on('newmessage')
def updatemessage(data):
    print("initialised")
    channels[channel][name][0] = data["msg"]
    channels[channel][name][1] = data["time"]
    print(f" this is the update channel info : {channels}")
    m = channels[channel]
    print(f"m is :  {m}")
    emit('message loader', m, broadcast=True)
```

Now problem is that when I click the button with class name `sendmessage` then `socket.emit('newmessage', {'channel': channel, 'name': name, 'msg': msg, 'time': time});` is not being functional, as I cannot see any print statements displaying output on terminal for `@socket.on(sendmessage)` part in the flask that I have specified. On other hand, the loadmessage is working fine. I can't figure it out properly as I am new to sockets.

Comment: Your code checks for a `classname == 'list'`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Miguel I tried keeping things seperate as well, but no luck. The socket.emit() for 'new message' is not linking with flask, else I would have an output in terminal as those print statements I've set for debugging.

Comment: hey I checked it out and found out there was some problem with this line `const name = document.querySelector('#displayname').data("displayname");`  and now it's working perfectly. Thanks for drawing my attention to Javascript as I was in belief that it must have been `socket.emit()` part that's creating the problem @Miguel